# mySQL Unexpected token on delete

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I have problem with multi delete query in PHP myadmin(storage engine InnoDB). This is my database:
[image: database schema]

This is my query:

```
DELETE placement, employees
FROM placement, employees
WHERE placement.id_emp = employees.id_emp
AND employees.id_emp = 113;
```

**Errors:**

3 errors were found during analysis.

> Unexpected token. (near "placement" at position 7)
>       Unexpected token. (near "," at position 16)
>       Unexpected token. (near "employees" at position 18)
>
> 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`employment`.`placement`, CONSTRAINT `placement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_emp`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id_emp`))

I wrote that query according to this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `"DELETE FROM placement, employees USING placement, employees WHERE ..."` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. It returns even more errors: 

4 errors were found during analysis.
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "USING" at position 33)
    Unexpected token. (near "placement" at position 39)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 48)
    Unexpected token. (near "employees" at position 50)

Comment: And by trying INNER JOIN? Like this : 'DELETE placement, employees
FROM placement INNER JOIN employees ...'

Comment: Tired - result: 
3 errors were found during analysis.

    Unexpected token. (near "placement" at position 7)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 16)
    Unexpected token. (near "employees" at position 18)

Comment: Sorry I can't help I guess.. :/

Comment: Np, thanks for your effort anyway:) I will try it on another computer, maybe there's a problem with phpmyadmin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Even it is old post, but may be someone will need help in future also, so updating here-

There seems 2 issues.

First foreign key issue: to take care this issue you need to either first delete records from child table then you can delete from master table. But if you want to bypass it (which is not recommended) you can do as per below:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
<YOUR DELETE STATEMENT>; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Note: it will skip foreign key check.

Second issue seems with SQL syntax, even I did not verify it. So you can write code as per below:

If you want to delete data from single table like from employees then use it:

```
DELETE employees.*
FROM placement, employees
WHERE placement.id_emp = employees.id_emp
  AND employees.id_emp = 113;
```

If you want to delete data from both tables like from employees as well placement then use it:

```
DELETE placement.*, employees.*
FROM placement, employees
WHERE placement.id_emp = employees.id_emp
  AND employees.id_emp = 113;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put ; at the end of the line before this code.

Comment: Unexpected token on delete" is an error message that typically occurs when there is an issue with the syntax of a DELETE statement in MySQL. This can happen if there is a typo or a missing comma, or if a keyword is used in the wrong context. In order to fix the error, you will need to examine the DELETE statement that is causing the problem and make sure that the syntax is correct

Comment: There is no need to create a response for this type of information. One comment is enough :)